# Value getting round off

Tags: java, types

```
class Faculty{

    private String  name;
    private float basicSalary;
    private float bonusPercentage;
    private float carAllowancePercentage;

    public Faculty(String name , float basicSalary){
        this.name = name;
        this.basicSalary  = basicSalary;
        this.bonusPercentage = 4f;
        this.carAllowancePercentage = 2.5f;
    }

    public double calculateSalary(){
        float bonus  =  ( (bonusPercentage /  100 ) *  getBasicSalary() );
        float carAllowance =(  ( (float)carAllowancePercentage / (float) 100 ) * getBasicSalary() );

        return (getBasicSalary() + bonus + carAllowance);
    }


    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public float getBasicSalary() {
        return basicSalary;
    }

    public void setBasicSalary(float basicSalary) {
        this.basicSalary = basicSalary;
    }

    public float getBonusPercentage() {
        return bonusPercentage;
    }

    public float getCarAllowancePercentage() {
        return carAllowancePercentage;
    }

    public void setCarAllowancePercentage(float carAllowancePercentage) {
        this.carAllowancePercentage = carAllowancePercentage;
    }
}

public class overriding1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

       
        Faculty f = new Faculty("henry",30500.0f);
        System.out.println(f.calculateSalary());

    }
}
```

Whenever I am running this it is showing the below output, but the expected output is different . I check all the possible but nothing works.

I am getting output: **32482.5**
but the expected output is: **32482.498046875**

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3uk4u.png)

**Please Help me with this**

Updated:   **double facultySalary= this.getBasicSalary()*  (1+
(this.getBonusPercentage()/100)+(this.getCarAllowancePercentage()/100));**

When I am running with the above-updated formula, I am getting expected output, can anyone explain please to me why both formulae are giving values like this because logically both are the same.

Comment: Maybe check your values and computations and make sure they are the same with yours, beacause correct answer is as Peter Knali below says

Comment: can you explain how you got `32482.498046875` as expected value? Seems like some rounding error.

Comment: and that is one of the main reasons not to use primitive floating point types (`float` and `double`) to represent monetary values! Prefer `BigDecimal` instead - Check [What Every Programmer Should Know About
Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://www.phys.uconn.edu/~rozman/Courses/P2200_15F/downloads/floating-point-guide-2015-10-15.pdf) ,  [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) , and more on the internet

Answer (score 0):

32482.5 is the correct answer.

Base allowance: 30,500

Bonus: 30500 * 4.0 / 100 = 1220.0

Car Allowance: 30500 * 2.5 / 100 = 762.5

Total: 32482.5.

Why do you expect 32482.498046875? It looks like all of those calculation end in numbers a float value can represent without any loss of accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

> This will work fine 
> just write factorize the formula and you are all done.  But the calculation is not actually correct mathematically.

```
class Faculty{

    private String  name;
    private float basicSalary;
    private float bonusPercentage;
    private float carAllowancePercentage;

    public Faculty(String name , float basicSalary){
        this.name = name;
        this.basicSalary  = basicSalary;
        this.bonusPercentage = 4f;
        this.carAllowancePercentage = 2.5f;
    }

    public double calculateSalary(){
    

        return basicSalary * (1 + bonusPercentage/100 + carAllowancePercentage 
                                         /100);
    }


    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public float getBasicSalary() {
        return basicSalary;
    }

    public void setBasicSalary(float basicSalary) {
        this.basicSalary = basicSalary;
    }

    public float getBonusPercentage() {
        return bonusPercentage;
    }

    public float getCarAllowancePercentage() {
        return carAllowancePercentage;
    }

    public void setCarAllowancePercentage(float carAllowancePercentage) {
        this.carAllowancePercentage = carAllowancePercentage;
    }
}

public class overriding1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

       
        Faculty f = new Faculty("henry",30500.0f);
        System.out.println(f.calculateSalary());

    }
}
```